# Boost.spirit (x3, boost 1.64): how to implement this recursive rule correctly, is it possible?

Tags: c++, recursion, boost, c++14, boost-spirit-x3

The question is easy to formulate. I have a recursive rule, I do not know the synthesized attribute type for the rule, but I also have a few more questions about the inner workings.

It looks to me that the return type is `variant<tuple<return_type_of_a, SEQ>, tuple<return_type_of_b, SEQ>>` where `SEQ` is a recursive rule and `a` and `b` are terminals:

```
rule<class myrule, ??> SEQ = a >> SEQ | b >> SEQ;
```

The following is not accepted because the rule is recursive, and I cannot figure out the return type exactly:

```
rule<class myrule, decltype (a>> SEQ | b >> SEQ)> seq = a >> seq | b >> seq;
```

1. must I know the return type of the recursive rule?
2. it looks like there must be some type of type nesting, this is natural to recursion, but if it is not flattened it is impossible to calculate the return type at compile-time. So how is the type for a recursive rule calculated at compile-time? there is any kind of flattening?
3. what should be the synthesized of the rule above?
4. would it help to refactor the rule to:

`rule<class myrule, ??> SEQ = (a | b) >> SEQ;`

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What you call "return type" is "synthesized attribute type"

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean @sehe

Comment: I know :) I'm just letting you know so you can improve the question/future questions/looking for information in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. About

   > ```
   > seq = a >> seq | b >> seq;
   > ```

   First and foremost: your grammar is strictly circular and never parses: it will infinitely recurse the rule, until mismatch. I'm going to assume you wanted something like:

   ```
   expr = var | "!" >> expr;
   ```

   (Note how not all branches recurse unconditionally).
2. > how to implement this recursive rule correctly, is it possible?

   Yes. The tutorial samples should probably show this.

### Sample

Let's say we have a very very simple grammar like

```
expr = var | '!' >> expr;
```

We create an AST to reflect that:

```
namespace Ast {
    using var = std::string;
    struct negated;

    using expr = boost::variant<var, boost::recursive_wrapper<negated> >;

    struct negated {
        expr e;
    };

}
```

### The Rules

Because the `expr` rule is going to be recursive, we have to declare it before its definition:

```
    static x3::rule<struct expr_, Ast::expr> expr {"expr"};
```

Let's imagine it's already defined, we would write the sub expressions like:

```
    auto var = x3::rule<struct var_, Ast::var> {"var"}
             = x3::lexeme [ x3::alpha >> *x3::alnum ];

    auto neg = x3::rule<struct var_, Ast::negated> {"neg"}
             = "!" >> expr;
```

All that's left is the recursive rule itself: `BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE`

```
    auto expr_def = var | neg;

    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(expr)
```

That's all.

### DEMO TIME

Let's add some test cases:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fcf2a9a0415e8ec9)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct.hpp>

namespace Ast {
    using var = std::string;
    struct negated;

    using expr = boost::variant<var, boost::recursive_wrapper<negated> >;

    struct negated {
        expr e;
    };

    static inline std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, Ast::negated const& n) {
        return os << "NOT(" << n.e << ")";
    }
}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Ast::negated, e)

namespace Parsers {
    namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

    namespace detail {
        static x3::rule<struct expr_, Ast::expr> expr {"expr"};

        auto var = x3::rule<struct var_, Ast::var> {"var"}
                 = x3::lexeme [ x3::alpha >> *x3::alnum ];

        auto neg = x3::rule<struct var_, Ast::negated> {"neg"}
                 = "!" >> expr;

        auto expr_def = var | neg;

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(expr)
    }

    auto demo = x3::skip(x3::space) [ detail::expr ];
}

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    for (std::string const input : { "foo", "! bar", "!!!qux" }) {
        auto f = input.begin(), l = input.end();

        Ast::expr e;

        if (parse(f, l, Parsers::demo, e)) {
            std::cout << "Parsed: " << e << "\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "Parse failed\n";
        }

        if (f != l)
            std::cout << "Remaining unparsed input: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Parsed: foo
Parsed: NOT(bar)
Parsed: NOT(NOT(NOT(qux)))
```

And optionally (`#define BOOST_SPIRIT_X3_DEBUG`)

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f44faac82dbe986a)</kbd>**

```xml
<expr>
  <try>foo</try>
  <var>
    <try>foo</try>
    <success></success>
    <attributes>[f, o, o]</attributes>
  </var>
  <success></success>
  <attributes>[f, o, o]</attributes>
</expr>
Parsed: foo
<expr>
  <try>! bar</try>
  <var>
    <try>! bar</try>
    <fail/>
  </var>
  <neg>
    <try>! bar</try>
    <expr>
      <try> bar</try>
      <var>
        <try> bar</try>
        <success></success>
        <attributes>[b, a, r]</attributes>
      </var>
      <success></success>
      <attributes>[b, a, r]</attributes>
    </expr>
    <success></success>
    <attributes>[[b, a, r]]</attributes>
  </neg>
  <success></success>
  <attributes>[[b, a, r]]</attributes>
</expr>
Parsed: NOT(bar)
<expr>
  <try>!!!qux</try>
  <var>
    <try>!!!qux</try>
    <fail/>
  </var>
  <neg>
    <try>!!!qux</try>
    <expr>
      <try>!!qux</try>
      <var>
        <try>!!qux</try>
        <fail/>
      </var>
      <neg>
        <try>!!qux</try>
        <expr>
          <try>!qux</try>
          <var>
            <try>!qux</try>
            <fail/>
          </var>
          <neg>
            <try>!qux</try>
            <expr>
              <try>qux</try>
              <var>
                <try>qux</try>
                <success></success>
                <attributes>[q, u, x]</attributes>
              </var>
              <success></success>
              <attributes>[q, u, x]</attributes>
            </expr>
            <success></success>
            <attributes>[[q, u, x]]</attributes>
          </neg>
          <success></success>
          <attributes>[[q, u, x]]</attributes>
        </expr>
        <success></success>
        <attributes>[[[q, u, x]]]</attributes>
      </neg>
      <success></success>
      <attributes>[[[q, u, x]]]</attributes>
    </expr>
    <success></success>
    <attributes>[[[[q, u, x]]]]</attributes>
  </neg>
  <success></success>
  <attributes>[[[[q, u, x]]]]</attributes>
</expr>
Parsed: NOT(NOT(NOT(qux)))
```

Comment: Hello @sehe. I will accept this reply, which is good already and very helpful, if you can reply to 4. 3. is not important anymore because of your explanation, but I am wondering if the rule can be refactored to what I proposed int question 4. Actually the example is a bit simplified, after seq there is a terminal a >> seq >> eoi. Would that work?

Comment: Yes. And it wouldn't make a difference. See the first paragraph of my answer.

Comment: Great tip the debug tree :) I do not have much time to play around and make documentation due to more tasks and I accessed the docs on a per-need basis, so this helps a lot :)

Comment: I cannot recommend learning Boost Spirit when pinched for time. It's a great productivity booster once you do get past the learning curve, of course.